# How to make a calculation based on a value and multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column, that should do a calculation per product, based on multiple columns.

Logic for the calculation column:

- Calculations should be done per product
- Use quantity as default
- IF promo[Y/N] = 1, then take previous weeks quantity * season perc. change.
- Except when the promo is on the first week of the product. Then keep quantity as well.

In the example below, You see the calculation column (I placed comments for the logic).

```
week    product    promo[Y/N]   quantity    Season       calculation 
  1       A           0           100          6            100 # no promo, so = quantity col
  2       A           0           100          10           100 # no promo, so = quantity col
  3       A           1           ?            -10           90 # 100 (quantity last week)- 10% (season)
  4       A           1           ?            20           108 # quantity last week, what we calculated, 90 + 20% (18) = 108.  
  5       A           0           80            4            80 # no promo, so = quantity col

  1       B           1           100          6            100 # Promo, but first week of this product. So regular quantity. 
  2       B           0           100          10           100 # no promo, so = quantity col
  3       B           1           ?            -10           90 # 100 (quantity last week)- 10% (season)
  4       B           1           ?            20           108 # quantity last week, what we calculated, 90 + 20% (18) = 108.  
  5       B           0           80            4            80 # no promo, so = quantity col
```

I tried to solve this in two ways:

1. Via a groupby(), and then the Product, but this was messing up my end file (I would like to have it in the format above, so with 1 additional column.
2. By looping over the dataframe with iterrows(). However, I messed up, because it doesn't distinct between products unfortunately.

Anyone an idea what a proper method is to solve this? Appreciated!

Comment: I would try the `apply` method for dataframes. It allows you to define a function that can perform this task to then pass to the `apply` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using custom apply function to add column to dataframe

**Code**

```
def calc(xf):
    '''
        xf is dataframe from groupby
    '''
    calc = []
    # Faster to loop over rows using zip than iterrows
    for promo, quantity, season in zip(xf['promo[Y/N]'], xf['quantity'], xf['Season']):
        if not np.isnan(quantity):
            calc.append(quantity)           # not missing value
        elif promo and calc:                # beyond first week if calc is not None
            prev_quantity = float(calc[-1]) # previous quantity
            estimate = round((1 + season/100.)*prev_quantity) # estimate
            calc.append(estimate)
        else:
            calc.append(quantity)           # use current quantity
            
    xf['calculated'] = calc                 # Add calculated column to dataframe
    return xf
```

**Test**

```
from io import StringIO

s = '''week    product    promo[Y/N]   quantity    Season
  1       A           0           100          6
  2       A           0           100          10
  3       A           1           ?            -10
  4       A           1           ?            20
  5       A           0           80            4
  1       B           1           100          6
  2       B           0           100          10
  3       B           1           ?            -10
  4       B           1           ?            20
  5       B           0           80            4'''

# convert '?' to np.nan (missing value so column become float)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep = '\s{2,}', na_values = ['?'], engine = 'python')
print(df.type)

# Output
```

> ```
> week            int64
> product        object
> promo[Y/N]      int64
> quantity      float64
> Season          int64
> dtype: object
> ```

```
tf = df.groupby('product').apply(calc)
print(tf)

# Output

   week product  promo[Y/N] quantity  Season calculated
0     1       A           0      100       6        100
1     2       A           0      100      10        100
2     3       A           1        ?     -10         90
3     4       A           1        ?      20        108
4     5       A           0       80       4         80
5     1       B           1      100       6        100
6     2       B           0      100      10        100
7     3       B           1        ?     -10         90
8     4       B           1        ?      20        108
9     5       B           0       80       4         80
```

Comment: Appreciated, Not sure why, but the 'if quantity.isnumeric(): leads to an error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Comment: @Roverflow with `df.dtypes`, what is the type for the `quantity` column?  I would expect it to be object since there "?" in the quantity column (i.e. string).  Did you convert the '?' to np.nan so the column becomes float?

Comment: Hi DarrylG, the quantity column has float64 in it

Comment: @Roverflow since it is float64--how do have "?" for some values?  This is easily handled but just wondering why the type is different from what's shown in your post.

Comment: @Roverflow I updated my answer to show how the data types.

Comment: @Roverflow 1) Add converter to read_csv so missing value '?' is converted to np.nan (allowing column to become float) and 2) modified function `calc` to check for nan values.

Answer (score 2):

groupby() is a good approach in my opinion.

Let's build our dataset first :

```py
csvfile = StringIO(
        """week\tproduct\tpromo\tquantity\tseason
        1\tA\t0\t100\t6 
        2\tA\t0\t100\t10
        3\tA\t1\tnan\t-10
        4\tA\t1\tnan\t20
        5\tA\t0\t80\t4 
        1\tB\t1\t100\t6
        2\tB\t0\t100\t10
        3\tB\t1\tnan\t-10
        4\tB\t1\tnan\t20
        5\tB\t0\t80\t4""")
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep='\t', engine='python')
```

I strongly encourage to not use '?' or other non numeric character to transcript the lack of data. It will be a mess in your future analysis. Instead use np.nan.

Then let's build a function hich will translate your expected behaviour for each product :

```py
def computation(pd_input):
    previous_calculation = np.nan
    # output dataframe
    pd_output = pd.DataFrame(index=pd_input.index, columns=["calculation"])

    # we need to loop other all your row
    for index, row in pd_input.iterrows():
        # if promo = 0 OR for the first row, use quantity
        if row.promo == 0 or np.isnan(previous_calculation):
            pd_output.loc[index, "calculation"] = row.quantity
        # else, use the previous value we computed and apply the percentage
        else:
            pd_output.loc[index, "calculation"] = (1 + row.season/100) * previous_calculation
        previous_calculation = pd_output.loc[index, "calculation"]

    # return the pandas
    return pd_output
```

Finally we just need to apply the previous function to our grouped dataframe :

```py
calculation = df.groupby("product", group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: computation(x))
```

Let's check our ouput :

```py
print(calculation )
```

```
          calculation
product              
A       0       100.0
        1       100.0
        2        90.0
        3       108.0
        4        80.0
B       5       100.0
        6       100.0
        7        90.0
        8       108.0
        9        80.0
```